# Angular2: making Angular2 recognize directive added dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript

Is it possible to add directive dynamically? For example I have

*dynamic.directive.ts*

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[diynamicdirective]'
})
class DiynamicDirective {
}
```

*app.component.ts*

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  template: `
     <div  id="sample">
       Sample
     </div>
  `
})
class App {}
```

bootstrap this app.component.ts will parsed to something like this

```
<html>
 .
 .
  <body>
    <div  id="sample">
       Sample
     </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

when the application is running, I want to add diynamicdirective, for some reasons I dont want to use "local variable" like this

```
<div #dynamiclocalvar id="sample">Sample</div>

@ViewChild('dynamiclocalvar', { read: ViewContainerRef }) dynamiclocalvar: ViewContainerRef;

this.renderer.setElementAttribute(this.dynamiclocalvar.nativeElement, "diynamicdirective", '');
```

instead I want to use jQuery like this

```
$( "#sample" ).attr( "diynamicdirective" );
```

but yeah I've read some documentation and the other SO discussions that dynamically added element or attribute outside direct angular2 template wont be recognized.

Is there a solution to this problem, I've tried RuntimeCompiler to recompile template (like $compile in angularJS or angular 1). but still no luck or Am I missing something? please help.. thank you in advance